# How to change string to a method or a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to make a string to become an attribute:

```
Model:
    Author
    attr_accessible :book1, book2, book3 etc...
```

I would like to retrieve 20 books in a lesser command

```
def do_something 
  self.book1     
  self.book2     
  self.book3     
  ....           
end
```

This is a solution I came up with but how can I make the string become an attribute so I could retrieve the data.

```
def do_something             
  count = 0                  
  10.times do                
    self."book#{count += 1}"  
  end                        
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
def do_something             
  count = 0                  
  10.times do                
    self.send("book#{count += 1}")  
  end                        
end
```

Also try this, it's simpler and it should work as well: `self[:book1]` or `self['book1']`

BTW this is weird design. Consider using array of books instead:

```
attr_accessible :books

...

self.books.each { |book| puts book }

self.books[0] # etc.
```

Comment: I might be using self[:book1] thanks for the info I'll be doing:

count = 0
10.times do
  self["book#{count += 1 }".to_sym]
end

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`.

```
10.times do
  eval("self.book#{count} = count}")
end
```

Comment: `eval` just evaluates any string to a ruby expression. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval

Comment: *eval(string)* - runs string as if it were a command. it's slow and insecure. *self.send(method_str, params)* - calls self.method_str(params)